# Can a nested function dependent on objects in outer function be separated to another .py file to clean up code?

Tags: python, nested-function

Sorry if this question sounds too general, but I have a motivation in mind. 
 Suppose in python we first start a function such

```
def f1(arguments):
   #insert some statements such as
   x=27
   yz=['string']
  return(whatever)
```

then  go on to insert a function within f1 such that the overall code becomes

```
def f1(arguments):
       #insert some statements such as
       x=27
       yz=['string']
       def f2():
          newthing=x
       #more code for f2
         return(whatever)

       #rest of code for f1
    return(whatever from f1)
```

Notice the "newthing" in f2 depends on something from f1... which seems to work fine in practice when all this code is written out explicitly in the same .py file.  But   here is my question basically:

Suppose I wanted to write the code for f2 in a separate f2.py file  so that I didn't have to show the code explicitly in f1.py.   Perhaps the code from f2 is LOOONG and it would be nice to clean things up a bit on the surface.  Is it possible some  import statements could be used for doing such?  Or Am I right to  worry about the apparent entanglement of f1 and f2 in this case making such impossible?with f1 depending on f2 yet f2 depending on f1.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. Python uses lexical scoping. `f2()` can only refer to `f1()`'s functions if it's nested textually within it.

If you want to separate functions, you should pass the needed variables as parameters and return values.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to declare f2 outside of f1 and just call f2 in f1

```
def f2(value): 
   blah blah blah 


def f1: 
   value = 4
   f2(value) 
   blah blah blah
```

Hope that makes sense!